# How to change UITextView's width to be that of longest line of text?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a UITextView with 4 lines of text inside. I want the UITextView's width to fit the exact length of the longest line. Currently, the textview is wider than the longest text.

This is the current size of the textView:

```
| Textline 1                                        |
| Textline 2                                        |
| Textline 3 -longest Text                          |
| Textline 4                                        |
```

This is the size of textView I want it to be:

```
| Textline 1               |
| Textline 2               |
| Textline 3 -longest Text |
| Textline 4               |
```

How can I achieve that in swift?

Comment: How are you adding the text to the text view? And should it get wider if more text is added to the longest line?

Comment: @Carpsen90 - the text is added dynamically when the parent view instantiates this ViewController and added the view to its subview.

Answer (score 0):

Set a width for your textView and add it as an outlet to your ViewController.

After that when you set the text inside your textView set this contraint as the width of your textView's contentSize like this

```
textView.text = //Your text
textViewWidthConstraint.constant = textView.contentSize.width
```

Like this your constraint should get automatically the size of what textView is containing and can adapt the width.

Try it and tell me if it work for you

Comment: My bad! I fixed it with width :)